# jquery dropdown menu bug :/

Tags: jquery

I just created my dropdown menus and my news ticker plugins. (The new ticker plugin written by alexfish.)

Plese check the live codes [here](http://fatihtoprak.com/wp-content/works/).

The problem is, when you mousehover on the second link : Elbise Modelleri , the sublevel menu doesnt display when you go the second menu item.

I think you can catch to hard sub menu items over the news ticker area.:/ Any help. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed. It was about **Cufon replecament**. (: The topic could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify CSS

> ```
> .PozHeader .Menus ul li:hover > ul {
>     visibility:visible;
>     z-index:1
> }
> ```

Comment: just double checked, everything is working. If the problem was an overlapping of the drop-downs

Comment: it works but check the "elbime modelleri"'s sub menus please. it hard to catch it.

Comment: remove the css with .trans class

Comment: and my advise: don't use this ancient cufon text-replacement, cool guys use font-face

Comment: i recently found the problem thanks for advice, it was complatelly about cufon replacement. So do you know any smilar font like this in Google Web fonts.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an jQuery issue, it's a CSS issue. Add `position: relative; z-index: 100` to your menu `ul` element and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

replace jquery `.hover()` method with `.mouseenter()` (respectively `.mouseleave()`)

see if this working

Comment: i confuse about 

`mouseenter`and `mouseleave` tried some but couldnt get it :/